# Problems in Installing e(fx)clipse In Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin, javafx, efxclipse

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. 
Im using Eclipse Kepler Enterprise Edition( Version: Kepler Service Release 2 Build id: 20140224-0627). 
I want to install JavaFx ( e(fx)clipse ) in my kepler version.
1. I've tried to install it from Eclipse Market place it gave me the error like e(fx)clipse will not be installed. [image]
I've searched about this error i found http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/629144/ but it dint helped me.

so i've choosen another option to install e(fx)clipse, and i found the steps at http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html#for-the-ambitious

2. When i'm trying to install using those mentioned steps i found the erros like

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. 
Software being installed: e(fx)clipse - IDE - Kepler 0.9.0.201401250805 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.all.kepler.feature.feature.group 0.9.0.201401250805)

Missing requirement: e(fx)clipse - IDE - FXGraph 0.9.0.201401250805 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.fxgraph.feature.feature.group 0.9.0.201401250805) requires 'org.eclipse.xtext.sdk.feature.group 2.5.0' but it could not be found

Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: e(fx)clipse - IDE - Kepler 0.9.0.201401250805 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.all.kepler.feature.feature.group 0.9.0.201401250805)

To: org.eclipse.fx.ide.fxgraph.feature.feature.group [0.9.0.201401250805]

After that I've deleted my eclipse current version and I've downloaded the same version( Eclipse Kepler Enterprise Edition) once again and tried to install e(fx)clipse once again even then i've got the same problems.

Can some one help me with this issue for installing JavaFX in Eclipse Kepler Enterprise Edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is xtext which is a requirement for e(fx)clipse - I'd suggest to get started right away to download a prepackaged distro from http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/install.html.

I'll give the instructions a try tomorrow myself to see what is failing. I'll also update the prepackaged distro to 4.3.2 so that you get the lastest bits.

Comment: I'm using Java Jdk7. I have downloaded the package from the link which you have provided above ( http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/install.html.).After that I've created a JavaFX project but it is giving the errors as " Application Cannot be resolved to a type " ( Acutally Application is a package which is created by the eclipse itself ).And for import, main, borderpane for all these statements it is giving the same error.

Comment: So what jdk do you have the distro jdks maybe does not have javafx. Download a jdk from oracle and use that to launch eclipse